# filtering a dataframe in spark use "in a set" clause

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using `pyspark`. I have a spark dataframe `my_sdf` whose `col1` is integers and I predefined a list of integer

```
S1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

Then I want to return the rows in my `my_sdf` where the `col1` in the set `S1`. So I did the following:

```
Test1 = my_sdf.filter(my_sdf.col1 in S1).cache()
# or Test1 = my_sdf.filter(my_sdf.col1 not in S1).cache()
Test1.count()
```

But it returns

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Eventually, I would like to start `S1 = []` to be an empty list as the starting point in my iteration and during the loop, I will update the `S1`. Similarly, the `not in S1` also does not work. I've tried to write

```
Test1 = my_sdf.filter((my_sdf.col1 <10) & (my_sdf.col1>2)).cache()
```

It works, but if I use the filtering condition `in S1`, then it does not work.

Another question is: what does this `cache()` stuff is doing? will that makes a difference if I don't put that? I was told that spark is `lazy` for evaluating the code, so before I call `Test.count()`, it actually does not execute the previous filtering command. But I am not sure how exact this `cache()` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use isin

For your problem, you can try something like this :

`from pyspark.sql.functions import col`

`Test1 = my_sdf.where(col("col1").isin(S1))`

Based on my understanding, cache is used to save the current value of your dataframe. It is helpful because if you want to use that dataframe again, spark will take the values from the cache, not computing it again from the beginning. So, if your code only do `Test1.count`, then caching or not doesn't really matter. CMIIW

Comment: Thanks! I also played with it, I found for `not in`, we could use ` my_sdf.where((col("col1").isin(S1)) & (~col("col1").isin(S2)) )`

Comment: Another question I had is: what if `S1` is not a python list, but a pyspark dataframe with one column which looks like `[Row(S=9527), Row(S=36)]`, then I tested this `isin` function does not work. Do you have any idea to still make it work?